# Máquina Dobradora

Tags: c, array, dev-c++

Estou estudando para um desafio de programação na Faculdade e meu professor deu alguns exercícios de programação para treinar. Foi proposto o da máquina dobradora, porém não estou conseguindo desenvolver o processo de entrada, no qual a pessoa atribui vários valores para a máquina realizar o processamento. Se alguém puder me ajudar aqui está o [link](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1470) do teste.

O trecho que estou com dificuldade é este: "A linha seguinte conterá N inteiros v1, . . . , vN , correspondentes ao conteúdo da fita de entrada". A dificuldade que tenho é de manipular os dados entrados e jogá-los em um vetor, sendo cada valor em uma posição.

O trecho do código que consegui fazer até o momento é este:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

main() {

 int tamanho =0, i=0;


 printf("Qual o tamanho da Fita?\n");
 scanf("%i", &tamanho);

char variaveis[tamanho];

    printf("Insira os %i numeros", tamanho );
    scanf("%i", &variaveis[i]);

//  for(i=1; i<=tamanho; i++){
//      printf("Insira numero na posicao %i ", i );
//      scanf("%i", &variaveis[i]);
//      }

    for(i = 1; i<=tamanho; i++){
    printf("Os valores digitados foram: %i\n", variaveis[i]);   
    }
return 0;
}
```

O programa funcionará basicamente assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Tem duas opções:

- Cria um ciclo/laço e pede ao utilizador para digitar um valor a cada iteração e guarda directamente no array; ou
- Pede ao utilizador para digitar os valores numa única linha, separados por um espaço. Usando a função strtok extrai os números para um array.

Deixo aqui a implementação da segunda alternativa (a primeira, mais simples, fica como exercicio)

Usando o seu código como base:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Esta função "parte" a linha passada na variável entrada e tenta obter um máximo de numEntradas. Os números extraidos são guardados no array saida
*/
int lerNumeros(int numEntradas, char *entrada, int saida[])
{
    int numAux;
    char *numero = strtok(entrada, " ");

    int i = 0;
    while (numero != NULL && i < numEntradas)
    {
        sscanf(numero, "%i", &numAux);
        saida[i++] = numAux;

        numero = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    return numEntradas == i;
}

int main()
{
    static const int TAMANHO_MAXIMO = 15;
    static const int ENTRADA_MAXIMA = 1000;

    int tamanho = 0;
    char entrada[ENTRADA_MAXIMA];
    int fita[TAMANHO_MAXIMO];

    //pedir o tamanho da fita;
    printf("Qual o tamanho da Fita? ");
    fgets(entrada, sizeof(int), stdin);
    sscanf(entrada, " %d", &tamanho);

    //pedir numeros ao utilizador
    int sucesso = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("Insira na mesma linha, separados por espaços, os %i numeros : ", tamanho);
        fgets(entrada, ENTRADA_MAXIMA, stdin);

        sucesso = lerNumeros(tamanho, entrada, fita);

    } while (sucesso == 0);

    //mostrar fita
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
        printf("Os valores digitados foram: %i\n", fita[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note que o código está incompleto, em particular não é efectuada validação dos dados introduzidos pelo utilizador (por exemplo, validar que este introduziu um número inteiro e não introduziu apenas lixo)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda bruno, eu fiz o Laço para pedir números individualmente, mas acho que sairia fora do proposto, precisaria da segunda opção que você mencionou. Irei testar logo menos, e marco aqui sua pergunta como aceita ou não Ok. obrigado